# Merging sub-arrays with common elements in multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, compare

I am working on a game powered by PHP. I have a system that can randomly generate maps with pathways in them. Here is an example:

http://i1244.photobucket.com/albums/gg579/Xeniar117/Map.png

(I updated this post without enough rep for this image to stay directly posted to page that someone else made possible by using their rep to do it, sorry)

Each cell of the map has a 4-digit string assigned to it denoting travel (W,N,E,S). So, cell 11 from the map above would have a string of 1110 and cell 17 would have one of 1001.  This string (aka NavString) is randomly generated within rules to prevent it from sending players off the map.

Any cells with only 1 direction of travel are put into $endcaps (array). Also, any cells with 3 and 4 directions of travel are put into $endcaps but with as many entires into $endcaps as directions of travel (eq, a 3 way intersection gets 3 entries into $endcaps) Cells with only 2 directions arent added in, thats because they have 1 way in and only 1 different way out, so its a straight path in and out; no branches outward nor any dead ends.

I foreach loop through $endcaps to get a starting point for each section of path I am to record. Using the NavString, I follow each path from the cell gathered from $endcaps until I get to another cell thats in $endcaps (using in_array($endcaps)), the entire time recording the cell numbers its passing through into $paths[$path][$step]. Every new $endcap I $path++ and every new cell between $endcaps I $step++.

Here is an example of how $paths looks after it comes out of the loop:
[Note: The map in the image is where this 2D array came from]

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4
        [1] => 9
        [2] => 14
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 6
        [1] => 5
        [2] => 10
        [3] => 11
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 6
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 2
        [3] => 7
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 6
        [1] => 7
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 6
        [1] => 11
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 7
        [1] => 6
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => 7
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 6
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [0] => 7
        [1] => 12
        [2] => 11
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8
        [1] => 13
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [0] => 11
        [1] => 10
        [2] => 5
        [3] => 6
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [0] => 11
        [1] => 6
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [0] => 11
        [1] => 12
        [2] => 7
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [0] => 13
        [1] => 8
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [0] => 13
        [1] => 14
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [0] => 13
        [1] => 18
        [2] => 19
        [3] => 14
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [0] => 14
        [1] => 13
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [0] => 14
        [1] => 9
        [2] => 4
    )

[17] => Array
    (
        [0] => 14
        [1] => 19
        [2] => 18
        [3] => 13
    )

[18] => Array
    (
        [0] => 16
        [1] => 17
        [2] => 22
        [3] => 23
    )

[19] => Array
    (
        [0] => 23
        [1] => 22
        [2] => 17
        [3] => 16
    )

)
```

I want to compare like values in the sub arrays to other sub arrays in $paths. If there is 1+ matches then I want to merge the two arrays together and continue looking for sub-arrays with at least 1 common value BUT I need to allow any new additions to be added in the comparison.

So ideally, that should consolidate to a 2D array with only 3 sub-arrays after all is said and done. The *desired* result of the above example should look like this:

```
array (
    array(1,2,5,6,7,10,11,12)
    array(4,9,14,8,13,18,19)
    array(16,17,22,23)
)
```

The above would be a perfect representation of the pathways that I can then use to ensure that the entrance and the exit are connected and the player wont get trapped!

So my question is how can I go about refining $paths (in the first code block) down to the array in the 2nd code block? Remember, these maps are generated randomly so $paths can have any amount of sub-arrays and the sub-arrays can have any amount of elements, which can be any cell number (depending on how the system happened to generate the paths)

I hope thats enough detail for you guys to help me, last time I asked how to do this they said I way too vague (and after some reflection upon it I agree). If its not enough, well...

---

**UPDATE** What I've tried so far

```
$set=0;
foreach($paths as $loop1key=>$loop1) {
  foreach($paths as $loop2key=>$loop2) {
    if(count(array_intersect($loop1,$loop2)) > 0) {
      $consolidated = array_merge($loop1,$loop2);
      unset($paths[$loop2key],$paths[$loop1key]);
      $loop1 = $consolidated;
    }
  }
  $after[$set]=$consolidated;
  $set++;
}
```

AND (proposed by @hackerartist):

```
$after = array();
foreach($paths as $numArray) {
  $addedKey = -1;
  foreach ($after as $key=>$conArray) {
    if ($addedKey<0&&count(array_intersect($conArray,$numArray))){
      $a‌​fter[$key]=array_unique(array_merge($after[$key],$numArray));
      $addedKey = $key;
    }
    if ($addedKey>=0 && count(array_intersect($after[$addedKey],$numArray))) {
      $after[$addedKey] = array_unique(array_merge($after[$addedKey],$after[$key]));
      unset($after[$key]);
    }
  }
  ‌​if ($addedKey<0) {
    $after[] = $numArray;
  }
}
```

---

**UPDATE #2** I tweaked my second attempted (The one right there^^^) and it seems to work 99% of the time, however it still fails to consolidate some path sections into their correct grouping. My entire source code is below with the tweak surrounded by comments. (Lines 141-158 according to PHP Expert Editor)

```
<?php
$rows = 5;//Set statically to test, will be random in final version
$cols = 5;//Same as rows, will eventually be a random value
$gridsize = $rows * $cols;

for($r=0;$r<$rows;$r++){//Loop as many times as $rows
    for($c=0;$c<$cols;$c++){//Loop as many times as $cols
        $cell = ($r * $cols) + $c;//Current cell ((Current row * Total Columns) + Current Column)
        if($r == 0 && $c > 0 && $c < ($cols - 1)){//North edge cell
            $west = $cells[$cell - 1][2];
            $east = rand(0,1);
            $south = rand(0,1);
            $string = $west."0".$east.$south;
        } elseif ($r > 0 && $r < ($rows - 1) && $c == 0){//West Edge
            $north = $cells[$cell - $cols][3];
            $east = rand(0,1);
            $south = rand(0,1);
            $string = "0".$north.$east.$south;
        } elseif ($c == ($cols - 1) && $r > 0 && $r < ($rows - 1)){//East Edge
            $west = $cells[$cell - 1][2];
            $north = $cells[$cell - $cols][3];
            $south = rand(0,1);
            $string = $west.$north."0".$south;
        } elseif ($r == ($rows - 1) && $c > 0 && $c < ($cols - 1)){//South Edge
            $west = $cells[$cell - 1][2];
            $north = $cells[$cell - $cols][3];
            $east = rand(0,1);
            $string = $west.$north.$east."0";
        } else {//Either a Corner or Core Cell
            switch($cell){
                case '0'://NW Corner
                    $east = rand(0,1);
                    $south = rand(0,1);
                    $string = "00".$east.$south;
                break;
                case ($cols - 1)://NE Corner
                    $west = $cells[$cell - 1][2];
                    $south = rand(0,1);
                    $string = $west."00".$south;
                break;
                case ($gridsize - $cols)://SW Corner
                    $north = $cells[$cell - $cols][3];
                    $east = rand(0,1);
                    $string = "0".$north.$east."0";
                break;
                case ($gridsize - 1)://SE Corner
                    $west = $cells[$cell - 1][2];
                    $north = $cells[$cell - $cols][3];
                    $string = $west.$north."00";
                break;
                default://Core cell
                    $west = $cells[$cell - 1][2];
                    $north = $cells[$cell - $cols][3];
                    $east = rand(0,1);
                    $south = rand(0,1);
                    $string = $west.$north.$east.$south;
                break;
            }
        }
        for($x=0;$x<4;$x++){
            if($string[$x]==1){
                $totalnav++;
                $dirs[]=$x;
            }
        }
        if($totalnav == 1 || $totalnav > 2){
            $endcaps[$cell]=$dirs;
        }
        unset($totalnav);
        unset($dirs);
        $cells[] = $string;
    }
}


//Determine center
foreach($cells as $cellnum=>$cell){
    $center = $cell[0]+$cell[1]+$cell[2]+$cell[3];
    if($center > 0){$cell .= "10000";}
    else{$cell.="00000";}
    $blocks[]=$cell;
}

//Refine rooms
for($r=0;$r<$rows-1;$r++){
    for($c=0;$c<$cols-1;$c++){
        $nw = ($r * $cols) + $c;//Current Cell Number
        $ne = $nw + 1;
        $sw = $nw + $cols;
        $se = $ne + $cols;
        $loop = 0;
        if($blocks[$nw][2]==1&&$blocks[$nw][3]==1){$loop++;}
        if($blocks[$ne][0]==1&&$blocks[$ne][3]==1){$loop++;}
        if($blocks[$sw][1]==1&&$blocks[$sw][2]==1){$loop++;}
        if($blocks[$se][0]==1&&$blocks[$se][1]==1){$loop++;}

        if($loop == 4){//Loop detected, creating room
            $blocks[$nw][8]=1;
            $blocks[$ne][7]=1;
            $blocks[$sw][6]=1;
            $blocks[$se][5]=1;
            $loop=0;
        }
    }
}

$path=0;
$oppnodes = array(0=>array(2,-1),1=>array(3,($cols*-1)),2=>array(0,1),3=>array(1,$cols));
foreach($endcaps as $cellnumber=>$directions){
    foreach($directions as $direction){
        $step=0;
        $paths[$path][$step++]=$cellnumber;
        $nextcell = $cellnumber + $oppnodes[$direction][1];
        $nextnode = $oppnodes[$direction][0];
        $end=0;
        while($end==0){
            if(!isset($endcaps[$nextcell])){
                //Pass the torch from last to current
                $currentcell = $nextcell;
                $currentnode = $nextnode;

                $nav = substr($cells[$currentcell],0,4);//Grab nav string from current cell.
                $nav[$currentnode]=0;//Disable opposite node from direction last traveled
                for($x=0;$x<4;$x++){
                    if($nav[$x]=="1"){
                        $nextnode = $oppnodes[$x][0];
                        $nextcell = $currentcell + $oppnodes[$x][1];
                    }
                }
                $paths[$path][$step]=$currentcell;
            } else {
                $paths[$path][$step]=$nextcell;
                $end=1;
            }
            $step++;
        }
        $path++;
    }
}

//Problem area start ===================================================
$after = array();
foreach($paths as $arrayOfNumbers) {
    $addedKey = -1;
    foreach($after as $key=>$newArrayOfNumbers){
        if($addedKey < 0 && count(array_intersect($arrayOfNumbers,$newArrayOfNumbers))){
            $after[$key] = array_unique(array_merge($arrayOfNumbers,$newArrayOfNumbers));
            $addedKey = $key;
        } elseif($addedKey >= 0 && count(array_intersect($after[$key],$newArrayOfNumbers))){
            $after[$key] = array_unique(array_merge($after[$key],$newArrayOfNumbers));
            unset($paths[$key]);
        }
    }
    if($addedKey<0){
        $after[] = $arrayOfNumbers;
    }
}
//Problem area end ===================================


echo"<table><tr><td valign=top>Array Representation of Paths In Map<BR><PRE>";print_r($after);echo"</PRE></td><td valign=top>";


echo "<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=1>";
for($r=0;$r<$rows;$r++){
    echo "<tr>";
    for($c=0;$c<$cols;$c++){
        $cellnum=($r*$cols)+$c;
        $cell = current($blocks);
        echo "<td>";
        $directions = array("west","north","east","south","center","nwcorner","necorner","swcorner","secorner");
        foreach($directions as $num=>$direction){if($cell[$num]==1){
            $$direction="white";}else{$$direction="black";}}
        echo "<table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
                <tr>
                    <td width=15px height=15px bgcolor=$nwcorner></td>
                    <td width=20px height=15px bgcolor=$north></td>
                    <td width=15px height=15px bgcolor=$necorner></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width=15px height=20px bgcolor=$west></td>
                    <td width=20px height=20px bgcolor=$center align=center><font color=blue>$cellnum</font></td>
                    <td width=15px height=20px bgcolor=$east></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width=15px height=15px bgcolor=$swcorner></td>
                    <td width=20px height=15px bgcolor=$south></td>
                    <td width=15px height=15px bgcolor=$secorner></td>
                </tr>
            </table>";
            echo "</td>";
            next($blocks);
        foreach($directions as $direction){unset($$direction);}
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
unset($blocks);
echo "</td></tr></table>";
unset($after);
?>
```

I am not asking for you to check my entire code mind you, just the problem area to see if you can figure out why it misses a consolidation every so often. Posting the entire source seems like the most logical way to allow you to see the actual results I get. The source doesn't require any external sources nor does it require a special file name. I just can't figure out why it works 99% of the time without any problems but then there is that 1/100 times that it will fail to consolidate a path section into its correct group. I will keep researching on my own of course but any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

---

**UPDATE #3** So close!

I have been tinkering with some code proposed by hackerartist here at StackOverflow that, with some tweaking, works how I want it to 99% of the time. Unfortunately, 99% isn't acceptable. The code is supposed to merge the subarrays with any common elements to any other sub-arrays in a multidimensional array like this:

```
$array = array(
    array(6,5,0,1,6),
    array(6,11),
    array(11,10,15,16,17,12),
    array(11,12),
    array(12,13),
    array(18,19,14),
    array(7,8,3,4)
);
```

Into an array like this:

```
$array = array(
    array(0,1,5,6,11,10,15,16,17,12,13),
    array(18,19,14),
    array(7,8,3,4)
);
```

Heres the code I'm using to try accomplish this:
$paths would be $array above.

```
for($x=0;$x<count($paths);$x++){//Loop through paths
                $paths = array_values($paths);//Reset keys
                for($y=0;$y<count($paths);$y++){//Loop through again
                    if($x != $y){//If we arent on the same array
                        if(count(array_intersect($paths[$x],$paths[$y]))){//If there is even 1 matching element
                            $paths[$x] = array_unique(array_merge($paths[$x],$paths[$y]));//Merge arrays
                            unset($paths[$y]);//Remove array just merged
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
```

There is also the tweaked version of hackerartist's proposed solution:

$paths2 would be an array like $array above

```
foreach($paths2 as $arrayOfNumbers) {
                $addedKey = -1;
                foreach($after as $key=>$newArrayOfNumbers){
                    if($addedKey < 0 && count(array_intersect($arrayOfNumbers,$newArrayOfNumbers))){
                        $after[$key] = array_unique(array_merge($arrayOfNumbers,$newArrayOfNumbers));
                        $addedKey = $key;
                    } elseif($addedKey >= 0 && count(array_intersect($after[$key],$newArrayOfNumbers))){
                        $after[$key] = array_unique(array_merge($after[$key],$newArrayOfNumbers));
                        unset($paths2[$key]);
                    }
                }
                if($addedKey<0){
                    $after[] = $arrayOfNumbers;
                }
            }
```

Now, they may work for the example I provided but when you use the system I made to generate the arrays those codes are supposed to work with, like I said, they miss an array or two that is supposed to get merged into another one with common element(s) every 1 out of 100 times (estimation!!!) I pass a different array with different elements in each sub-array through the code.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how to correct this flaw?

Comment: Can I ask what you've tried up to now?

Comment: Hehe, do you mind if I update your original post with that? It'll be vastly more readable.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the most elegant solution but its working 100% of the time. Quite simply, I am running it through the refining code twice, using the output of the first time through for the second time through then returning it out of the function on the second time. The re-call is embedded in the function itself (so I guess that means its a recursive function right?) Anyway, here's an example of an array that won't refine down all the way (it misses a merge):

```
$array= Array
(
    [0] => Array(
            [0] => 1,
            [1] => 0,
            [2] => 5,
            [3] => 6,
            [4] => 11),
   [3] => Array(
            [0] => 10,
            [1] => 11),
    [4] => Array(
            [0] => 11,
            [1] => 12),
    [5] => Array(
            [0] => 12,
            [1] => 17),
    [6] => Array(
            [0] => 15,
            [1] => 16)
    [7] => Array(
            [0] => 17,
            [1] => 18,
            [2] => 23,
            [3] => 22),
    [8] => Array(
            [0] => 17,
            [1] => 22),
    [9] => Array(
            [0] => 21,
            [1] => 22));
```

Running it through once produced this:

```
$array = Array(
    [0] => Array(
            [0] => 21,
            [1] => 22,
            [2] => 17,
            [4] => 18,
            [5] => 23,
            [6] => 12,
            [7] => 11,
            [8] => 10,
            [9] => 1,
            [10] => 0,
            [11] => 5,
            [12] => 6),

    [1] => Array(
            [0] => 7,
            [1] => 12,
            [2] => 2,
            [3] => 3,
            [4] => 4,
            [5] => 9,
            [6] => 8),

    [2] => Array(
            [0] => 15,
            [1] => 16));
```

This isn't quite right since $array[0][6] and $array[1][1] are both 12 and the arrays they are in should have been combined, but they didn't. I'm not sure why it doesn't get it but I figure a simple solution is to run it through again and that works. Heres the completed function:

```
function linkSegments($paths=array(),$ranthru=1){
               if(is_empty($paths)){
                 echo "No segments to link!";die;
               } else {
            for($x=0;$x<count($paths);$x++){//Loop through paths
                $paths = array_values($paths);//Reset keys
                for($y=0;$y<count($paths);$y++){//Loop through again
                    if($x != $y){//If we arent on the same array
                        if(count(array_intersect($paths[$x],$paths[$y]))){//If there is even 1 matching element
                            $paths[$x] = array_unique(array_merge($paths[$x],$paths[$y]));//Merge arrays
                            unset($paths[$y]);//Remove array just merged
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            if($ranthru == 1){
                $paths = linkSegments($paths,$ranthru=2);
                return $paths;//Set path data to class
            } else {
                return $paths;
            }
               }
        }
```

Calling $refinedArray = linkSegments($array) [using $array from the first code block] will produce the correct result:

```
$array = Array(
    [0] => Array(
            [0] => 21,
            [1] => 22,
            [2] => 17,
            [4] => 18,
            [5] => 23,
            [6] => 12,
            [7] => 11,
            [8] => 10,
            [9] => 1,
            [10] => 0,
            [11] => 5,
            [12] => 6,
            [13] => 7,
            [14] => 8,
            [15] => 9,
            [16] => 2,
            [17] => 3,
            [18] => 4),

    [1] => Array(
            [0] => 15,
            [1] => 16));
```

And if you know of a more efficient way of doing this please tell me! Its for a game so the faster I can make this happen the better :D